# Entity Framework Core LINQ Class Property/Methods can't use Included Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a `User` class with navigation property `Settings` and a readonly Property `IsVisibleInApp`.

At present this code works:

```
var users = context.Users.Include(x => x.Settings)
   .Where(x => x.Settings.IsApproved && x.Settings.IsAvailable && x.UserType == 2);
```

But I have to use these checks frequently, so I try to use a property and it gets `Settings` as null at runtime.

Here is my code.

```
public bool IsVisibleInApp
{
  get
  {
    return this.Settings.IsApproved && this.Settings.IsAvailable && this.UserType == 2;
  }
}

...
...

void SomeMethod(){
    var users = context.Users.Include(x => x.Settings)
       .Where(x => x.IsVisibleInApp).ToList();
```

I can see that the foreign key `this.SettingsID` is a valid value. I guess properties/methods can't be used in `Where` clauses on `DBSets` as they get converted to SQL? 
But surely there is a way around this... Or do I have to do a `.ToList()` first and then use a further `.Where` call, but that would mean pulling all the rows from the database which seems like a lot of extra work...

Comment: I think you answered your own question. Why would your database understend your C# code, or why would LINQ try to translate any random piece of C# code you throw at it into SQL? It can translate the original lambda, but not getter of the property. If that would work, next you include a service-call or I/O to another database in that getter and still expect the whole thing to be executed on your DB-server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do it the way you want (EF will not go inside your property getter and look what you are doing there), but you can reduce code repetition by wrapping that in static expression:

```
public static Expression<Func<User, bool>> IsVisibleInAppExpression = x =>
    x.Settings.IsApproved && x.Settings.IsAvailable && x.UserType == 2;
```

And then use like this:

```
var users = context.Users.Include(x => x.Settings)
   .Where(User.IsVisibleInAppExpression).ToList();
```

Or by creating extension method:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static IQueryable<User> VisibleInAppOnly(this IQueryable<User> query) 
    {
         return query.Where(x => 
             x.Settings.IsApproved && x.Settings.IsAvailable && x.UserType == 2);
    }
}
```

And using like this:

```
var users = context.Users.Include(x => x.Settings).VisibleInAppOnly();
```